Complete and fill missing rows with groups of uneven length
I have a dataframe of county executives and the year they were inaugurated. I am running a panel study with county-year as the unit of analysis. The date range is 2000 to 2004.
I will like to expand the df such that it lists who was the county executive during each year between the years 2000 and 2004, but some of the districts were created half-way through my period of analysis.
My starting point is this:
df <- data.frame(year= c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2003),
                  executive.name= c("Johnson", "Smith", "Alleghany", "Roberts", "Clarke", "Tollson", "Roland"),
                 party= c("PartyRed", "PartyYellow", "PartyGreen", "PartyYellow", "PartyOrange", "PartyRed", "PartyPurple"),
                  district= c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1003))

  year executive.name       party district
1 2000        Johnson    PartyRed     1001
2 2001          Smith PartyYellow     1001
3 2003      Alleghany  PartyGreen     1001
4 2000        Roberts PartyYellow     1002
5 2002         Clarke PartyOrange     1002
6 2004        Tollson    PartyRed     1002
7 2003         Roland PartyPurple     1003

So I want my df to only include years that the district existed, like below:
df.neat <- data.frame(year= c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2003, 2004),
                  executive.name= c("Johnson", "Smith", "Smith", "Alleghany", "Alleghany", "Roberts", "Roberts", "Clarke", "Clarke", "Tollson", "Roland", "Roland"),
                  party= c("PartyRed", "PartyYellow", "PartyYellow", "PartyGreen", "PartyGreen", "PartyYellow", "PartyYellow", "PartyOrange", "PartyOrange", "PartyRed", "PartyPurple", "PartyPurple"),
                  district= c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1003))

> df.neat
   year executive.name       party district
1  2000        Johnson    PartyRed     1001
2  2001          Smith PartyYellow     1001
3  2002          Smith PartyYellow     1001
4  2003      Alleghany  PartyGreen     1001
5  2004      Alleghany  PartyGreen     1001
6  2000        Roberts PartyYellow     1002
7  2001        Roberts PartyYellow     1002
8  2002         Clarke PartyOrange     1002
9  2003         Clarke PartyOrange     1002
10 2004        Tollson    PartyRed     1002
11 2003         Roland PartyPurple     1003
12 2004         Roland PartyPurple     1003

Note how district 1003 was established in 2003. If I run the complete command, it assumes that 2000, 2001, and 2002 are implicit NAs. And then fill drags down the last result from district 1002 to fill in those new rows.
In other words, my df turns out looking like this:
df |>
  tidyr::complete(district, year) |>
  tidyr::fill(executive.name, party)

# A tibble: 15 × 4
   district  year executive.name party      
      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>      
 1     1001  2000 Johnson        PartyRed   
 2     1001  2001 Smith          PartyYellow
 3     1001  2002 Smith          PartyYellow
 4     1001  2003 Alleghany      PartyGreen 
 5     1001  2004 Alleghany      PartyGreen 
 6     1002  2000 Roberts        PartyYellow
 7     1002  2001 Roberts        PartyYellow
 8     1002  2002 Clarke         PartyOrange
 9     1002  2003 Clarke         PartyOrange
10     1002  2004 Tollson        PartyRed   
11     1003  2000 Tollson        PartyRed   
12     1003  2001 Tollson        PartyRed   
13     1003  2002 Tollson        PartyRed   
14     1003  2003 Roland         PartyPurple
15     1003  2004 Roland         PartyPurple


We can use statar::fill_gap():
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(district) %>% 
  statar::fill_gap(year, full = TRUE) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(executive.name:party, .direction = "down") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>     year executive.name party       district
#>    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1  2000 Johnson        PartyRed        1001
#>  2  2001 Smith          PartyYellow     1001
#>  3  2002 Smith          PartyYellow     1001
#>  4  2003 Alleghany      PartyGreen      1001
#>  5  2004 Alleghany      PartyGreen      1001
#>  6  2000 Roberts        PartyYellow     1002
#>  7  2001 Roberts        PartyYellow     1002
#>  8  2002 Clarke         PartyOrange     1002
#>  9  2003 Clarke         PartyOrange     1002
#> 10  2004 Tollson        PartyRed        1002
#> 11  2003 Roland         PartyPurple     1003
#> 12  2004 Roland         PartyPurple     1003

Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.0.2

Using group_by(), this will work:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(year= c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2003),
                 executive.name= c("Johnson", "Smith", "Alleghany", "Roberts", "Clarke", "Tollson", "Roland"),
                 party= c("PartyRed", "PartyYellow", "PartyGreen", "PartyYellow", "PartyOrange", "PartyRed", "PartyPurple"),
                 district= c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1003))

df.neat <- df |>
  complete(district, year) |>
  group_by(district) |>
  fill(executive.name, party) |>
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(district, year) |>
  filter(!is.na(executive.name)) |>
  relocate(district, .after = last_col())

df.neat
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#     year executive.name party       district
#    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>          <dbl>
#  1  2000 Johnson        PartyRed        1001
#  2  2001 Smith          PartyYellow     1001
#  3  2002 Smith          PartyYellow     1001
#  4  2003 Alleghany      PartyGreen      1001
#  5  2004 Alleghany      PartyGreen      1001
#  6  2000 Roberts        PartyYellow     1002
#  7  2001 Roberts        PartyYellow     1002
#  8  2002 Clarke         PartyOrange     1002
#  9  2003 Clarke         PartyOrange     1002
# 10  2004 Tollson        PartyRed        1002
# 11  2003 Roland         PartyPurple     1003
# 12  2004 Roland         PartyPurple     1003


You could filter() as follows, before you fill()
  filter(row_number()>=min(which(!is.na(party))),.by = district) |>

Output:
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   district  year executive.name party      
      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>      
 1     1001  2000 Johnson        PartyRed   
 2     1001  2001 Smith          PartyYellow
 3     1001  2002 Smith          PartyYellow
 4     1001  2003 Alleghany      PartyGreen 
 5     1001  2004 Alleghany      PartyGreen 
 6     1002  2000 Roberts        PartyYellow
 7     1002  2001 Roberts        PartyYellow
 8     1002  2002 Clarke         PartyOrange
 9     1002  2003 Clarke         PartyOrange
10     1002  2004 Tollson        PartyRed   
11     1003  2003 Roland         PartyPurple
12     1003  2004 Roland         PartyPurple

Explanation:
After complete(), you have >=0 new rows for each district, and any new rows are NA for party. You only want to retain the existing rows and the new rows that have a row-index number that exceeds the row-index where the party is first non NA
df |>
  tidyr::complete(district, year) |>
  dplyr::filter(row_number()>=min(which(!is.na(party))),.by = district) |>
  tidyr::fill(executive.name, party)


Would you post your full code? I am a bit confused about filter() here.

See update with full solution
